# Dynamically changing databases in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, dynamic-sql

At work we have a number of databases that we need to do the same operations on.  I would like to write 1 SP that would loop over operations and set the database at the beginning of the loop (example to follow).  I've tried sp_executesql('USE ' + @db_id) but that only sets the DB for the scope of that stored procedure.  I don't really want to loop with hard coded database names because we need to do similar things in many different places and it's tough to remember where things need to change if we add another DB.

Any thoughts>

Example:
DECLARE zdb_loop CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT distinct db_id from DBS order by db_id

OPEN zdb_loop 
FETCH NEXT FROM zdb_loop INTO @db_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    USE @db_id

```
--Do stuff against 3 or 4 different DBs

FETCH NEXT FROM zdb_loop INTO @db_id
```

END

CLOSE zdb_loop
DEALLOCATE zdb_loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far looks like dynamic SQL is the only way to do this.  Pretty lame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stored procedure [sp_MSforeachdb](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) for this:

> This example will perform a database
>   backup, then a "DBCC CHECKDB" against
>   each database:

```
declare @cmd1 varchar(500)
declare @cmd2 varchar(500)
declare @cmd3 varchar(500)
set @cmd1 =
   'if ''?'' <> ''tempdb'' print ''*** Processing DB ? ***'''
set @cmd2 = 'if ''?'' <> ''tempdb'' backup database ? to disk=''c:\temp\?.bak'''
set @cmd3 = 'if ''?'' <> ''tempdb'' dbcc checkdb(?)'
exec sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@cmd1, 
                    @command2=@cmd2,
                    @command3=@cmd3
```

Comment: Here's what I did as a test:
SET @cmd =  'if ''?'' = ''int_tables'' use ''?'''
I get an syntax error near 'master'...(I get it for all DBs).

I'm going to play with it a bit today.

Comment: Changed it up a bit to:
SET @cmd =  'if ''?'' = ''int_tables'' use ?'

Unfortunately I get the same results as using SP_executesql, ie it only uses that db within the scope of the sp.